# Increasing count where a condition is met within pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

**How do I count the number of multicolumn *(thing, cond=1)* event occurrences prior to every *(thing, cond=any)* event?**

---

(These could be winning games of poker by player, episodes of depression by patient, or so on.) For example, row `index == 3`, below, contains the pair `(thing, cond) = (c,2)`, and shows the number of prior *`(c,1)`* occurrences, which is correctly (but manually) shown in the `priors` column as `0`. I'm interested in producing a synthetic column with the count of prior *(thing, 1)* events for every *(thing, event)* pair in my data. My data are monotonically increasing in time. The natural index in the `silly` `DataFrame` can be taken as logical ticks, if it helps. (<Narrator>: It really doesn't.)

For convenience, below is the code for my test `DataFrame` and the manually generated `priors` column, which I cannot get pandas to usefully generate, no matter which combinations of `groupby`, `cumsum`, `shift`, `where`, & etc. I try. I have googled and wracked my brain for days. No SO answers seem to fit the bill. The key to reading the priors column is that its entries say things like, "Before this (a,1) or (a,2) event, there have been 2 (a,1) events."

```
[In]:
import pandas as pd
silly = pd.DataFrame({'thing': ['a','b','a','c','b','c','c','a','a','b','c','a'], "cond": [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]})
silly['priors'] = pd.Series([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,1,3])
silly

[Out]:
silly
   thing  cond  priors
0      a     1       0
1      b     2       0
2      a     1       1
3      c     2       0
4      b     1       0
5      c     2       0
6      c     1       0
7      a     2       2
8      a     1       2
9      b     2       1
10     c     1       1
11     a     2       3
```

---

The closest I've come is:

```
silly
[In]:
silly['priors_inc'] = silly[['thing', 'cond']].where(silly['cond'] == 1).groupby('thing').cumsum() - 1

[Out]:

silly
   thing  cond  priors  priors_inc
0      a     1       0         0.0
1      b     2       0         NaN
2      a     1       1         1.0
3      c     2       0         NaN
4      b     1       0         0.0
5      c     2       0         NaN
6      c     1       0         0.0
7      a     2       2         NaN
8      a     1       2         2.0
9      b     2       1         NaN
10     c     1       1         1.0
11     a     2       3         NaN
```

Note that the values that are present in the incomplete priors column *are correct*, but not all of the desired data are there.

Please, if at all possible, withhold any "Pythonic" answers. While my real data are small compared to most ML problems, I want to learn pandas the right way, not the toy data way with Python loops or itertools chicanery that I've seen too much of already. Thank you in advance! (And I apologize for the wall of text!)

Comment: I'm open to tag suggestions, or for rewordings to hit people's search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

1. Cumulatively count where each "cond" is 1
2. Do this for each "thing"
3. Make sure the counts are `shift`ed by 1.

You can do this using `groupby`, `cumsum` and `shift`:

```
(df.cond.eq(1)
   .groupby(df.thing)
   .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

0     0
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     2
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    3
Name: cond, dtype: int64
```

---

Another option to avoid the `apply` is to chain two `groupby` calls—one does the shifting, the other performs the cumsum.

```
(df.cond.eq(1)
   .groupby(df.thing)
   .cumsum()
   .groupby(df.thing)
   .shift()
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

0     0
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     2
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    3
Name: cond, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm new at pandas. Is this the "pandemic" way? I was under the impression that `apply` was slow, and therefore a last resort? If not, I'm prepared to mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Yes, it is slow. But for operations where you need to do two things per group, such as shifting _and_ cumsumming, there is little option. Of course, the alternative is chaining two groupby calls which is slightly faster. This is in my answer as well.

Comment: Also, it is *pandaic or *pandorable :-)